# Validação mantendo estado nas requests

Tags: javascript

Criei um servidor express e uma classe para estruturar meus erros de validação. Ela é assim:

```js
function Error() {
  this.anyError = false
  this.errors = {}
}

Error.prototype.addError = function (attr, error) {
  this.anyError = true
  this.errors[attr] = error
}

module.exports = new Error()
```

Aí nas classes de validação eu utilizo esse modulo assim:

```js
const validator = require("validator")
const Error = require("./error")

function validateCustomer(body) {
  let helper = Error

  if ( ! validator.isEmail(body.email)) {
    helper.addError("email", "Invalid email.")
  }
  if ( ! validator.isLength(body.document, {min: 14, max: 14})) {
    helper.addError("document", "Invalid document.")
  }
  if ( ! validator.isLength(body.social_name, {min: 5})) {
    helper.addError("social_name", "Invalid social name, minimal length is 5.")
  }
  if ( ! validator.isMobilePhone(body.contact_phone, 'pt-BR')) {
    helper.addError("contact_phone", "Invalid mobile phone.")
  }

  return {
    invalid: helper.anyError,
    errors: helper.errors
  }
}

module.exports = {
  customerValidator: validateCustomer
}
```

A rota é o seguinte:

```js
router.post('/', [verifyAdmin, function(req, res) {
  if(req.body) {
    let validation = customerValidator(req.body.customer)
    if (validation.invalid) {
      return res.status(200).json({errors: validation.errors, status: 'invalid'})
    }
    // encripta a senha
    const newCustomer = new Customers(req.body.customer)
    newCustomer.encripted_password = customerCript(newCustomer.encripted_password)
    newCustomer
      .save()
      .then(function(customer) {
        delete customer.encripted_password
        res.status(201).json({message: 'record created successfully', customer})
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        res.status(500).json({error})
      })
  } else {
    return status(500).json({error: 'body not found'})
  }
}])
```

Toda vez que faço a submissão de algo que não é valido ele cai certinho na validação, mas assim que eu arrumo os dados é como se a validação estivesse persistente no servidor.

Com certeza eu fiz algo errado com relação ao `require`, escopo e etc. Poderiam por favor me ajudar?

Comment: Se eu fosse você, usaria um nome diferente de `Error` para a sua função, já que assim você está sobrescrevendo o [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) nativo do JavaScript. Talvez você já saiba disso. Apenas uma observação. :)

Comment: @LuizFelipe sabia não ! Obrigado

Comment: :) Acabei esquecendo de falar no outro comentário... Poderia incluir na sua pergunta o código da sua rota no express? Provavelmente o `app.post`...

Comment: @LuizFelipe Feito!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: O seu problema resume-se no seu módulo `Error`, que utiliza um singleton.

---

O problema surge no fato de você estar utilizando um padrão chamado **singleton** (saiba mais [nesse excelente vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPbybQdqcrE) do 
Waldemar Neto). Para entender, vamos rever o código:

<sub>PS: Omiti a implementação - irrelevante nesse contexto.</sub>

```js
function Error() {
}

Error.prototype.addError = function (attr, error) {
}

// Note abaixo que uma única instância será exportada por este módulo.
//               ↓↓↓
module.exports = new Error()
```

Conforme salientado pelo comentário, esse módulo exportará sempre a mesma instância de `Error`. Isso significa que a classe será instanciada na primeira vez que você importar o módulo e a partir daí, em todas as subsequentes importações o valor exportado será aquela mesma instância.

Nesse contexto, essa abordagem traz diversos problemas, uma vez que você está **reutilizando** a mesma instância desse mecanismo de validação por toda aplicação. Isso significa que **todas as requisições** compartilharão essa instância, logo, os erros acumular-se-ão a cada nova validação.

Isso acontece por conta do cache que o Node.js utiliza para importar os módulos utilizando o CommonJS (`require` *et al.*).

Portanto, a forma mais simples de se corrigir o problema é simplesmente não usar singleton:

```
function Error() {
}

Error.prototype.addError = function (attr, error) {
}

// Note agora que estamos exportando a classe. Isso assegurará que
// a sua instanciação seja realizada a cada requisição.
module.exports = Error
```

E sempre criar uma nova instância a cada requisição (no seu caso, dentro do método `validateCustomer`, que é chamado a cada *request*.

```js
const Error = require('./Error')

function validateCustomer(body) {
  // Note abaixo que estamos criando uma nova instância das sua
  // classe de validação sempre que a função `validateCustomer`
  // for chamada, isto é, a cada requisição. Isso resolve o seu problemas. :)
  let helper = new Error()

  // Condições omitidas.

  return {
    invalid: helper.anyError,
    errors: helper.errors
  }
}
```

Novamente, recomendo fortemente que você veja o [vídeo mencionado anteriormente](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPbybQdqcrE). Sem ele, não seria capaz, inclusive, de ter elaborado essa resposta. :)

Outros recursos relacionados:

- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton
- https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton <sup>[En]</sup>

---

E só para enfatizar: sugiro fortemente que você utilize um nome diferente de `Error` para a sua classe. Conforme já mencionei nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/401179/valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mantendo-estado-nas-requests#comment787391_401179), ao utilizar o nome `Error`, você está sobrescrevendo o [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) nativo do JavaScript.

Além disso, como você está utilizando uma nova versão do ECMAScript, *acho* que você deva usar a sintaxe de [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) para *talvez* facilitar:

```
// Note que já está com um nome diferente de `Error`. :)
class ErrorHelper {
  constructor() {
    this.anyError = false
    this.errors = {}
  }

  addError(attr, error) {
    this.anyError = true
    this.errors[attr] = error
  }
}

module.exports = ErrorHelper
```

Comment: Otimo exemplo :D

Comment: @WaldemarNeto já assisti seu vídeo, deu tudo certo.